# accessing mongodb from nodejs - common CRUD methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and nodejs.So far I have been able to create a new mongodb database and access it via nodejs. However I want to write some generic set of methods for accessing collections (CRUD), as my list of collections will grow in number. For example I have a collection which contains books and authors

```
var books = db.collection('books');
var authors = db.collection('authors');

exports.getBooks = function(callback) {
    books.find(function(e, list) {
        list.toArray(function(res, array) {
            if (array) callback(null, array);
            else callback(e, "Error !");
        });
    });
};
```

Similar to this I have the method for getting authors as well.Now this is getting too repetitive as I want to add methods for CRUD operations as well. Is there a way to have common/generic CRUD methods for all my collections ?

Comment: did you read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/crud/ yet?

Comment: Yes, I did read the docs.

Comment: When you read the documentation, why are you asking this question? Is there something in the documentation which isn't clear?

Comment: Its pretty clear. May be my question is not clear to you. I know how to do CRUD operations on a collection. But I want to write these CRUD methods in a way that all collections can be accessed using them. May be using mongoose somehow ?

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at Mongoose, it makes it easy to handle Mongodb from node.js, Mongoose js has a schema based solution, where each schema maps to a Mongodb collection, and you have a set of methods to manipulate these collections via models, that are obtained by compiling the schemas. I was exactly in the same place couple of months ago and have found that Mongoosejs is a good enough for all your needs.

Answer (score 1):

@Dilpa - not sure if you have looked at or are utilizing Mongoose [link](http://mongoosejs.com), but it can be helpful with implementing CRUD.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote my own service to handle very simple CRUD operations on mongodb documents.  Mongoose is excellent, but imposes structure on the documents (which IMO goes against the purpose of mongodb--if you're going to have a schema, why not just use a relational db?).

https://github.com/stupid-genius/MongoCRUD

This service also has the advantage of being implemented as a REST API, so it can be consumed by a node.js app or others.  If you send a GET request to the root path of the server, you'll get a screen that shows the syntax for all the CRUD operations (the GUI isn't implemented yet).  My basic approach was to specify the db and collection on the URL path `host/db/collection` and then pass the doc in the POST body.  The route handlers then just pass on the doc to an appropriate mongodb function; my service just exposes those methods in a pretty raw state (it does require authentication though).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @cpburnz: how's that?